# Use multiple WITH tablename AS (...) statements SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create two temporary tables and join them with a permanent table.  For example:

```
WITH temp1 AS (COUNT(*) AS count_sales, ID FROM table1 GROUP BY ID)
WITH temp2 AS (COUNT(*) AS count_somethingelse, ID FROM table2 GROUP BY ID)
SELECT *
FROM table3 JOIN table2 JOIN table1
     ON table1.ID = table2.ID = table3.ID
```

but there seems to be an issue having multiple WITH tablename AS (...) statments.  I tried a semicolon.

Comment: It's not the multiple `WITH`.  It's your query inside the `WITH` that has problem.  I don't see a `SELECT` statement in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query should look more like this:

```
WITH temp1 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_sales, ID
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY ID
     ),
     temp2 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_somethingelse, ID
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY ID
     )
SELECT *
FROM temp2 JOIN 
     temp1
     ON temp1.ID = temp2.ID;
```

Your query has multiple errors.  I would suggest you start by understanding why this version works -- or at least does *something* other than report on syntax errors.  Then, go back and study SQL some more.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but your criticism of my reporting on syntax errors is not useful.  I recognize the JOIN error after some more googling.  I ran into this problem yesterday, and believe me, google was not helpful.  I acknowledged that I am a SQL n00b, and this is my first stackoverflow post for SQL.

Comment: Hey, Choots... the helpful bit of info that Gordon left out is that what you're constructing is called a 'common table expression', or CTE. Many here are quick to criticize, but thoroughly unable to teach. The first step in learning/teaching is establishing terms and definitions.

He also failed to mention that you wanted a comma instead of a semicolon, as though he felt going on that journey yourself would make you wiser.

Googling 'SQL CTE' will probably be the best self-learning path. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create two temporary tables

Just for clarity... you used a CTE which is not quite the same thing as a temporary table.  You've also tagged 'temp tables', so you want a temp table?  You can store query results in a declared table variable or an actual temp table.

An example of declared table variables:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(id int, count_sales int) 

INSERT INTO @table1 (id, count_sales)
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
  FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
--or however you populate temp table1

DECLARE @table2 TABLE(id int, count_somethingelse int)

INSERT INTO @table2 (id, count_somethingelse)
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
  FROM table2
GROUP BY ID
--or however you populate temp table2

SELECT T3.id
      --,T2.(some column)
      --,T1.(some column)
      --,etc...
FROM table3 T3 INNER JOIN @table2 T2 ON T3.id = T2.id
               INNER JOIN @table1 T1 ON T3.id = T1.id
```